# Как правильно указать путь к директории php?

Tags: php

Есть у меня сайт. На сайте есть два каталога - `test` и `test1`. В `test` лежит `int.php` который должен загружать картинку в папку `int` в каталоге `test1`. В `int.php` указываю пусть `/test1/int/` и не работает. Если всё закинуть в корень сайта - работает, но тогда у меня все скрипты путаются и т.д. В общем, помогите.

Comment: `../test1/int/`

Comment: не работает, ноль действий :(

Comment: А можно узнать точку входа на ваш сайт?

Comment: это .htaccess что-ли? или index.php :/

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/paths

Comment: Использовал вот такой скрипт

<?php
echo 'Полный путь к каталогу: ';
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
echo '/';
?>
Получил полный путь, но все равно не работает. Если использовать "локальный" путь - работает.
Это если в test файл int.php будет загружать /test/int/